# WSO2 Admin services BAMMediatorConfigAdmin

Tags: web-services, admin, wso2

I am trying to add BAM server profile (under ESB server) using Admin Web services. I am not seeing any error thrown while executing as standalone program but profile is not getting added. Please advise if below steps are correct -

1. Get admin cookie by connecting to "AuthenticationAdmin" URL
2. Create stubs using wsdl2java from "BAMMediatorConfigAdmin" WSDL
3. String bamcepServerProfileServiceURL = Constant.SERVICE_URL + "BAMMediatorConfigAdmin";

   BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub   stub = new        BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub(bamcepServerProfileServiceURL);
4. ```
                   ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
           Options option = client.getOptions();
           option.setManageSession(true);
           option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, adminCookie);
   ```
5. ```
                   BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub.BamServerConfig bamConfig = new                      BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub.BamServerConfig();
           bamConfig.setUsername("admin");
           bamConfig.setPassword("admin");
           bamConfig.setLoadbalanced(false);
           bamConfig.setSecurity(true);
           bamConfig.setIp("localhost");
           bamConfig.setAuthenticationPort("7611");

           BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub.SaveBamServerConfig config = new BAMMediatorConfigAdminStub.SaveBamServerConfig();
           config.setBamServerConfig(bamConfig);

           stub.saveBamServerConfig(config);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check @addResource in[1], which creates the profile and calls ,

stub.saveResourceString(resourceString, bamServerProfileLocation);

through @saveResourceString in[2]

[1]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/components/mediators/bam/org.wso2.carbon.mediator.bam.config.ui/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediator/bam/config/ui/BamServerProfileUtils.java

[2]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/components/mediators/bam/org.wso2.carbon.mediator.bam.config.ui/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediator/bam/config/ui/BamServerProfileConfigAdminClient.java